# How to install iOS 10 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios10

I have an iOS app and I want to check if it's working fine on iOS 10.

I don't have an extra device so I need to check that on the simulator.

The problem is I can't find where to download iOS 10 simulator, am really need to install Xcode BETA or I can download the simulator separately?

Comment: install XCode 8 Beta....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if your aleady used **XCode8 beta** then follow the below steps, else if your **XCode < 8** then you need to upgrate or install the latest version of **XCode8 beta**

**Downloading and Installing Simulators**

> You install simulators in the Simulators pane of Components preferences. To open Components preferences, choose **Xcode** > **Preferences** and click **Components** at the top of the window.

for More Information see the  [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-documentation_preferences/Articles/DownloadingandInstallingXcodeComponents.html)

Comment: If I'll upgrade to Xcode 8 beta, will it be possible to run my project on Xcode 7 again?

Comment: @FS.O5 - in my suggestion may be it wrong , xcode8 is beta not a stable verson , so keep it both , else you can do

Comment: @FS.O5 - any other queries bro...?

Comment: but will it be possible to open the project in Xcode 7 after it?

Comment: I have Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) release version installed and there are no iOS10 simulators avaialbe in the components pane. iOS 9.3 is the highest. Is this a known issue?

Comment: @imobilizer how can i install iOS 10 simulator then?